# App runs fine from Xcode, but crashes when loaded from home screen

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-management, exc-bad-access

As the title suggests, I have an app that runs fine when launched from Xcode, but crashes when launched from the home screen.

Running build and analyze shows no memory leaks or warnings. (Although, I'm not ruling it out as a false sense of security.)

The corresponding Device Log shows:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0439e000
```

Which makes me think this is a release/retain issue, but why didn't it show up in Build/Analyze? And why would it run fine when running from Xcode?

**EDIT**

I should also note that the app "*runs*" fine in the simulator both from Xcode and from a home screen launch. I say "*runs*," because it uses the camera, so running on the simulator isn't all that useful in this case.

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks, all. All resources seem to be properly named. I'm trying to get the atos command to work properly. I keep getting the same address back instead of the class file name and line number.

Comment: It also happens with me, with every project, but only from the Simulator. Do you have this issue on the device?

Comment: This is actually on the device. (The log above is from the device and shown in the organizer, as you can't see console logs when running the app "unplugged".) Luckily I'm using snapshots after every major change, so worst case scenario, I could rewind back to a time where this wasn't happening and slowly piece it forward until it happens again, but I'd rather not do that many tweak/build/debug cycles.

Comment: Are you using iOS 5 beta? I've seen that happen with cocos2d-iPhone plans the beta sdk.

Comment: I'm currently targeting 4.3, actually. Thanks for checking.

Comment: Try to check u set proper nib name because device is case-sensitive so make problem when simulator is not.

Comment: @AJPatel is right, this is likely to be an issue with case sensitive filenames. When running on the simulator it will not matter but once on the device you will start having problems (i.e. a nib may not be getting loaded because of a wrong file name so when you try and accesses one of its views you are likely to get a crash).

Comment: Have you tried to archive the app and then run it to see if problems arise with release versions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Forget atos. I realized the Device Logs list which thread, file, and line number the crash occurred at. It's consistently in my AVCaptureSession delegate captureOutput method.

I was getting CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress values on the order of 200 times higher when run "unplugged". I also discovered that when I ran a simple diagnostic NSLog in one of the loops, the crashing stopped (but it prevented something on the main thread from being called, so this was not a permanent fix).

In the process, I made a stab in the dark tweak, removing an operation on the base address. In attempt to save loop iterations, I was doing something like this to skip every other pixel in the buffer:

```
byteIndex   += (bytesPerPixel * 2);
```

Dropping down to the following fixed the problem completely:

```
byteIndex   += (bytesPerPixel);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes (maybe in your case) when an app is first launched from the XCode it is build and run as a new instance of the application. When you then stopp it and try to run it from the home screen it might launch from background. If you didn't manage your memory properly for a state when your app launches from the background the analyzer will not pick up memory problems. 
To find out if that is the case, try to double click on the home button and quit your app if it appears there. Then launch it again from the home screen. You can also try to debug it with the instruments.

Comment: I did actually suspect that and did try this, but without success.